# Is there any evidence to suggest that Prevent Duty has lowered radicalization?

Tags: united-kingdom

### Context

As stated in [Prevent duty guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/prevent-duty-guidance):

> **Current guidance**
>
> The [Counter-Terrorism and Security Act 2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/counter-terrorism-and-security-bill) contains a duty on
>   specified authorities to have due regard to the need to prevent people
>   from being drawn into terrorism. This is also know as the Prevent
>   duty.
>
> In March 2015, Parliament approved guidance issued under section 29 of
>   the act about how specified authorities are to comply with the Prevent
>   duty. Specified authorities must have regard to this guidance when
>   complying with the Prevent duty.
>
> Two versions of the guidance were approved: one for specified
>   authorities in England and Wales, and one for specified authorities in Scotland.

---

### Question

Is there any evidence to suggest that this has been successful in lowering radicalization since it began?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost impossible to provide any sort of empirical evidence to prove that this law and/or the guidelines are effective. Let's say that the amount of terrorism drops in 2016 and 2017, how would we establish a causal relationship with this law? Terrorism is caused and influenced by many factors, and a law such as this is not exactly a watershed event such as a peace agreement or decisive military victory, at best it will *nudge* terrorism down.

For better or for worse, some political questions can't really be answered with any degree of certainty due to the extraordinary complexity of the world.

So **no**, this evidence does not exist, and is unlikely to ever exist. It is a personal judgement call.